# IllegalAccessException when trying to modify private static field

Tags: java, reflection

I tried to follow this [Change private static final field using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection)

But for some reason i get `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not set static final java.lang.Long field DataRepositoryTests.Item.id to java.lang.Integer`

```
for (Field field : Table.getDeclaredFields()){

                    System.out.println(Table.getSimpleName()); //prints "Item"
                    
                    field.setAccessible(true);

                    if (field.getName().equals(GeneratedValueFields.get(i).getName())) { 

                        System.out.println(field.getName()); //prints "id"

                        Field modifiersField = Table.getDeclaredField(GeneratedValueFields.get(i).getName()); 

                        System.out.println(modifiersField.getName()); //prints "id" as expected

                        modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
                        modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL); //error here

                        //data = 9 (Long)

                        field.set(null,data);


                    };
```

Now if i remove the line `modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);`

I get `java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Can not set static final java.lang.Long field DataRepositoryTests.Item.id to java.lang.Long`

If i change the field to just private final and specify a Object

```
field.set(TableModel,data);
```

It works properly

Comment: Isn't the `modifiersField` mean to be the `modifiers` field of the `field`? So when you try to set the modifiers, you are setting the value of your field, which hasn't had its modifiers changed yet.

Comment: @tgdavies it throws NoSuchMethodException :/

Comment: OK, but randomly changing the code to do something else is not going to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in [Change private static final field using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection) works in Java 1.8 but not in Java 17.

In Java 17 the `jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection` class contains a map of classes which should have some or all of their members made invisible to reflection:

```
    /** Used to filter out fields and methods from certain classes from public
        view, where they are sensitive or they may contain VM-internal objects.
        These Maps are updated very rarely. Rather than synchronize on
        each access, we use copy-on-write */
    private static volatile Map<Class<?>, Set<String>> fieldFilterMap;
    ...
    private static final String WILDCARD = "*";
    public static final Set<String> ALL_MEMBERS = Set.of(WILDCARD);

    static {
        fieldFilterMap = Map.of(
            Reflection.class, ALL_MEMBERS,
            ...
        );
        ...
    }
```

So the example will not work on newer JDKs.

This has been the case since Java 12: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8210496